# How to remove comments from HTML LXML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

How do you remove a comment like this using lxml without loosing the value Apple iPhone 5s (Space Grey, 16 GB)

```
<h1 class="_3eAQiD" data-reactid="144">
<!-- react-text: 145 -->
Apple iPhone 5s (Space Grey, 16 GB)
<!-- /react-text -->
</h1>
```

Comment: true. perhaps, stackoverflow needs to improve its related questions algorithm. Didnt even find via Google. Thanks

Comment: Not a duplicate.  The answers are different for XML and HTML.  One uses `etree.XMLParser`, the other uses `etree.HTMLParser` or `html.HTMLParser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Regex.**

```
import re    

a = '''<h1 class="_3eAQiD" data-reactid="144">
<!-- react-text: 145 -->
Apple iPhone 5s (Space Grey, 16 GB)
<!-- /react-text -->
</h1>'''    

print re.sub("(<!--.*?-->)", "", a, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

**Result:**

```
<h1 class="_3eAQiD" data-reactid="144">

Apple iPhone 5s (Space Grey, 16 GB)

</h1>
```

**Using lxml**

```
import  lxml.etree as et
x = et.fromstring(a, parser=et.HTMLParser(remove_comments=True))
print(et.tostring(x))
```

Comment: Regex is too slow. Will check out the LXML implementation and revert.

Comment: regexes to parse html/xml: now you have two problems.

Comment: You should not build a parser by yourself